# Passar parâmetro para template com Smarty

Tags: php, template

Estou lendo a documentação do `Smarty` mas ainda não consegui entender como posso e se posso passar parâmetro a uma template usando o `Smarty`.

Tenho esse trecho de código:

```
if ($part == PagePart::RecordCard && ($mode == PageMode::View || $mode === PageMode::ExportPdf)) {

    $cpf = GetApplication()->GetGETValue('pk0');

    $sql = "SELECT Opcao FROM dvsDecModelo WHERE CPF = '$cpf' ";
    $Opcao = $this->GetConnection()->ExecScalarSQL($sql);

    if ($Opcao == "Contrato") {
        $result = $mode === PageMode::ExportPdf ? 'TempModelo1Pdf.tpl' : '';
    } elseif($Opcao == "Adesão") {
        $result = $mode === PageMode::ExportPdf ? 'TempModelo2Pdf.tpl' : '';
    } else {
        $result = $mode === PageMode::ExportPdf ? 'TempModelo2Pdf.tpl' : '';
    }
}
```

Agora, no meu caso, preciso passar o resultado de uma consulta para a template, recupera-la e usa-la no corpo dessa template.

Existe essa possibilidade?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sim, é possível. Utilize o método `assign()` do smarty dois argumentos são passados o primeiro é identificador que valor terá e o segundo o próprio valor.

```
$template->assign('lista', $modelos);
```

[Documentação - assign()](https://www.smarty.net/docs/en/api.assign.tpl)

Comment: Obrigado @rray, grande ajuda, novamente.